# How do I install xemacs on my linode Debian 7 box?

Tags: debian, apt, linode

I have tried editing my /etc/apt/sources.list file on my linode with everything I can think of, but cannot seem to get xemacs to show up in the output of `aptitude -F "%p" search "?not(?installed)" | grep xemacs`
I know that xemacs is here:  https://packages.debian.org/sid/allpackages
But I don't know how to translate that into the magic on my linode.  For laughs, so you can all chuckle at my naivete, here is my /etc/apt/sources.list file, a total mess which I know hate even thinking about:

```
root@(none):/home/rcook# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.4.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20140208-13:45]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.4.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20140208-13:45]/ wheezy main
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US unstable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org unstable/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US unstable/non-US main contrib non-free

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US testing/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org testing/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free


deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Why in the world did I get modded down for asking a question?  Kind of baffling.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up compiling xemacs from source, after installing the prerequisite packages.  There is no debian package for xemacs available for Debian 7 that I know of.